# The getter 'menuBadge' was called on null

Tags: flutter

In my app I use `Stream` to check if values for `badges` are true or false.

```
 void _listenToBadges() {
   _subscription = activityFeedref
    .where('userId', isEqualTo: authUser.id)
    .snapshots()
    .listen((event) {
  allBadges.clear();
  for (final doc in event.docs) {
    allBadges.add(Badge.fromDocument(doc));
  }

  //print(allBadges);

  if (!isDisposed) {
    notifyListeners();
  }
 });
}
```

Then I save them in a class:

```
class Badge {
  Badge(
    {this.menuBadge = false,
     this.userId});

  Badge.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
   if (doc.data().containsKey('menuBadge')) {
     menuBadge = doc['menuBadge'] as bool;
    }
   if (doc.data().containsKey('userId')) {
     userId = doc['userId'] as String;
    }
   }
  bool menuBadge;
  String userId;
 }
```

and I use a getter to get the values of the badge:

```
  Badge get showFeedbadge {
      for (int i = 0; i < allBadges.length; i++) {
       if (allBadges.elementAt(i).userId == authUser.id) {
       print(allBadges.elementAt(i).menuBadge);
      return allBadges.elementAt(i);
    }
  }

   return null;
 }
```

Finally I user the value of `badge` to call badge in my `AppBar`:

```
       AppBar(
            leading: Builder(
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                final badgeManager = context.read<BadgeManager>();

                badge = badgeManager.showFeedbadge.menuBadge;
                return IconButton(
                  icon: BadgeIcon(show: badge, icon: Icon(Icons.menu)),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();
                    //badgeManager.updateMenuBadge(menuBadge);
                  },
                );
              },
            ),
```

But all the time the app initialises I get `The getter 'menuBadge' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: menuBadge`. Although the function is working, I don't know how I can get rid of this error. Do you guys have any idea?

Comment: where you call `Badge.fromDocument...`? in `Badge` class?

Comment: yes, that's right.

Comment: it seems it's only defined not used